# Access named nested list elements with string name in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to access named nested list elements by passing their names as a string (or list of strings). Something like you can do with `attr(the_thing, "the_attr")` but I want to do `attr(the_thing, "$attr1$attr2$attr3")`. Seems like this should be possible but I'm at a loss.

For example, I'm writing some code to consume responses from the Github API. There are a bunch of functions like (these are very simplified just for example's sake):

```
get_milestone <- function(org, repo) {
        response <- graphql_query(org = org, repo = repo)
        return(response$repository$milestone$issues)
}
get_pull_request <- function(org, repo) {
        response <- graphql_query(org = org, repo = repo)
        return(response$repository$pull_request$issues)
}
get_issues <- function(org, repo) {
        response <- graphql_query(org = org, repo = repo)
        return(response$repository$issues)
}
```

and you'll notice the only difference is what attributes you pull out of the response.

I'd like to make simple helper function like

```
get_something <- function(org, repo, attr_to_get) {
        response <- graphql_query(org = org, repo = repo)
        return(attr(response, attr_to_get))
}
```

and then call it each time like

```
get_something(org, repo, attr_to_get="$repository$milestone$issues")
get_something(org, repo, attr_to_get="$repository$pull_request$issues")
get_something(org, repo, attr_to_get="$repository$issues")
```

but that syntax doesn't work.

Is there any way to pass a string to specify nested attributes to extract from an object? I feel like rlang or something like that may be relevant, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My initial idea was just to do something like this

```
param_list <- unlist(strsplit(attr_to_get, "\\$"))
for (p in param_list) {
    if (p != "") {
       response <- response[[p]]
    }
}
```

But that feels very ugly and silly to me. Like, there must be a one-liner way of doing this without manually iterating. But maybe I should just do it that way? Any help is much appreciated.

**For reproducibility** you can replace the `response <- graphql_query(org = org, repo = repo)` line in my function with something like `response <- list(repository = list(milestone = list(issues=c("issue1", "issue2", "issue3"))))` and then attempt to extract `"$repository$milestone$issues"` from the response.
Thanks!

Comment: first `$repository$milestone$issues` is not an attribute. it is just a nested list. Are you dealing with nested lists or with `attributes`??

Comment: I'm dealing with nested lists.

Comment: well just use a vector instead of a string eg `response[[c("repository","milestone","issues")]]`

Comment: perfect. That works. Feel free to make an answer and I'll accept. Although I guess I should modify the question to be explicitly about nested lists.

Comment: The `purrr:pluck` function is also very helpful for extracting elements from nested lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do

```
 nm <- c("repository","milestone","issues")
 response[[nm]]
```

also we can use the `purrr::pluck` function

```
  purrr::pluck(response, !!!nm)
```

Comment: Similarly, `purrr::pluck(response, "repository", "milestone", "issues")`

Answer (score 2):

If you feel like using `rlang` here's another possible answer:

```
# Something generic that produces a nested list with the names you specified
graphql_query <- function(org, repo){
list(repository = list(milestone = list(issues = 'hi')))
}

get_something <- function(org, repo, ...) {
response <- graphql_query(org, repo)
attr_to_get <- paste0('response$', paste(rlang::list2(...), collapse = '$'))
rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::parse_expr(attr_to_get))
}

get_something('org', 'repo', 'repository', 'milestone', 'issues')
>>> [1] "hi"
```

or you can do:

```
att_lst <- c('repository', 'milestone', 'issues')
get_something('org', 'repo', !!!att_lst)
>>> [1] "hi"
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `parse_expr`. Building strings of code and executing them can be messy and dangerous. Especially given that the other answers already show safe, built-in ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution is to use `Reduce()` + `[[`

```
Reduce(`[[`,list(response,"repository","milestone","issues"))
```

or

```
Reduce(`[[`,list(response,c("repository","milestone","issues")))
```